# Template specialization for smart pointer exactly as normal pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, smart-pointers, template-specialization

Following code demonstrates the problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  // few members and methods...
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T*> {
  // different members and methods
};

A<int> ai; // invokes A<T>
A<int*> ap; // invokes A<T*>
A<shared_ptr<int>> as; // oops ! invokes A<T>
```

`A` is specialized for pointer types. Now at some places, I use smart pointer (say `shared_ptr`), which causes problem as shown in example.

One way is to copy the full `struct A<T*>` and rewrite for `struct A<shared_ptr<T>>`.  Is there **any elegant way** to invoke `A<T*>` type for `shared_ptr<>` also **?**

I am hopeful for following approach:

```
template<typename T>
struct A<shared_ptr<T>> : public A<T*> { /* empty */ };
```

Is there any problem with this approach ?

[The only potential problem will occur with following type of usage:

```
struct A<T*> {
  T* p;  // for A<int*> ... "typeof(p) = int*"
};

struct A<share_ptr<T>> : A<T*> {
  // oops! the "typeof(p)" is still "int*" and not "shared_ptr<int>"
};
```

Assume that, as of now this is not a concern.]

Comment: @GMan, all are normal `public` functions and they don't use `T*`.

Comment: `oops ! invokes A<T>` What exactly is wrong with that? What is it that `A` is doing that it needs a different interface for smart pointer types?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I want to invoke `A<shared_ptr<T>>` exactly as `A<T*>`. There are some differences between `A<T>` and `A<T*>`, which cannot be ignored.

Comment: @iammilind: Sorry, I mean what is the purpose of `A`? We can't really tell you what you should do without knowing how you want to use the template parameter. You may be able to get away with no specialization at all, for example.

Comment: @GMan, example: few methods inside `A<T>` are implemented differently than `A<T*>`. Or few methods are present in `A<T>` only and few only in `A<T*>`. In short `A<T>` and `A<T*>` are functionally different. I want `A<shared_ptr<T>>` to behave as `A<T*>`.

Comment: The "only potential problem" you mention will for one also happen with method arguments—and remember smart pointers never implicitly convert to their dumb counterparts—and for members of A it will break your automatic resource management. So the problem is not potential, it is quite real. Obviously depends on what members there are.

Answer (score 6):

With boost, you could make use of the [`has_dereference` type trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_dereference.html) and [MPL `if_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/if.html):

```
template<typename T>
struct Aobj { /* T is not a pointer */ };
template<typename T>
struct Aptr { /* T is a pointer-like type */ };

template<typename T>
struct A : public
  boost::if_<boost::has_dereference<T>, Aptr<T>, Aobj<T> >::type
{ /* implementation provided by base */ };
```

Comment: Why there are 2 `struct`s like `Aobj` and `Aptr` ? In my case `A<T>` and `A<T*>` are already existing in the code. I have to solve the problem of `A<shared_ptr<T>>`. I want to avoid touching the original `struct`s.

Comment: @iammilind, `if_` selects between two types (Aobj and Aptr here) based on a compile-time condition. We're basically making `A` just an alias for one of  the two implementations based on this arbitrary condition - in this case, `has_dereference`

Comment: @iammilind: You can't avoid touching the original structs if you want single definition to cover all kinds of smart pointers, because there is no way to write a partial specialization that covers them. So you'll have to use SFINAE and that requires changing the original definition. Either renaming it and using `if_` or disabling it with `enable_if`.

Comment: @JanHudec, how about the inheritance approach I showed in the question ? In that case, I am just writing one more specialization instead of touching the original `A<T>` and `A<T*>`.

Comment: @iammilind: It's not covering all kinds of smart pointers. If you need just that one, it's OK. But there are others (`weak_ptr`, `unique_ptr`) and some libraries have their own etc. So it depends on whether you want to handle just the few types you are using or want generic solution.

Comment: More importantly, if you use the inheritance approach and do something like `&*someptr` to pass pointers to the `T*` base, you'll have problems if the base stores the pointer, as you won't participate in reference counting

Comment: Is there a possibility to achieve this using C++11 specific constructs instead of boost?